# django FormWizard (formtools) how to dynamically change form_list based on request?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-formwizard, django-formtools

Would appreciate any guidance on this.
Have `SessionWizardView` from `django-formtools` and I want to be able to send in different forms based on which `request.user.restaurant` the user belongs to / `request.site` is being accessed.  Different restaurants are going to have different sets of forms for the signup flow and I can't figure out how to accommodate this.  It seems like I need to either pass in a list of firms in `urls.py` `.as_view()` or have the forms listed ahead of time in the class.

```
MY_TEMPLATES = {
    '0': '/templates/wizard_1.html',
    '1': '/templates/wizard_2.html',
    '2': '/templates/wizard_3.html'
}

class MySignupWizard(SessionWizardView):
    form_list = [AddressForm, MenuForm, HoursForm,ContactForm]

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [MY_TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
         etc.
```

Since `get_template_names(self)` has access to `self.request`, and `self.request.site`, I think I could have `MY_TEMPLATES` be a nested dictionary, and pass in `self.request.site` along with the current step to these.  Although is there a way to pass in data directly to these templates? Like do a query and pass in `Restaurant` data to each template?

But I can't figure out how to dynamically modify `form_list`. There are the standard four forms above, but some restaurants only want three forms or slightly different forms. I'd like to do something like :

```
restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(url=request.site.domain)
```

and then each restaurant has a list of forms to use, something like that. Set `form_list` or current form somehow.
Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the `get_form` method. I think you could play around with that to get the forms you want at each step; https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_form